# Select all links and forms without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, sizzle

How can I select all `a` and `form` tags without needing to include jQuery?

I ultimately am trying to do the following:

```
$("a").click(function {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});

$("form").submit(function {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

But I really would rather not include jQuery (or even Sizzle.js), if there's a more compact way to do that.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) like this:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );
for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  els[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){ window.onbeforeunload = null; } );
}
```

Similar for the `<form>` tags.

It is available in most modern browsers ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)).

Comment: I'm getting `'undefined' is not a function` for `var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );`...though if I run it directly in Web Inspector, it works. Some sort of `onload` thing I need to do, or something of the sort?

Comment: @Shpigford No setup should be required. Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: @Shpigford Can't double check on that one, sorry. The syntax, however, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Clicked"); window.onbeforeunload = null; });
}
```

To get the form submit, you can do something like this:

```
<script>
    do_function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; }
</script>
<form action="" onsubmit="do_function()" method="">
```

EDIT:
To combine the two:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Clicked"); window.onbeforeunload = null; });
}
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) { 
    forms[i].addEventListener("submit", function() { console.log("Submitted"); window.onbeforeunload = null; });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMHHx/)

Comment: Looks like browser support for this very good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName